# Null notifications from Android app when the notification is a New Meta question notification

Tags: bug, android-app

I can see notifications from Stack Exchange app but the title / description is null:null.

[image: null: null]

I remember that the notification was about a new Meta question posted. I haven't had a chat ping yet, so can't test out. Other notifications(comments/answers) seem to be fine

Comment: I've seen this too, but haven't been able to reproduce it reliably. Did the notification correspond to a chat ping by chance?

Comment: @shog not a chat ping but it was new Meta question notification - the notification I just received was correct

Comment: Which notifications are you talking about? Can you please attach snapshot of the same?

Comment: null null null null null null null null nullman!

Comment: @PareshMayani Shog has added a pic, similar to what I had

Comment: @Sathya I just got notification with "null notifications" title, can I include it in question?

Comment: @PareshMayani well the question title starts with Null notifications, so don't need to. Don't get confused with my question title & the bug ;)  (has happened to me few times already)

Comment: Keep an eye on this - it's possible I was in the middle of a recycle of our push server.  I'm not able to reproduce this yet.

Comment: I saw this after receiving multiple notifications from meta.  null notification was after someone answered my meta post question, and made comments on it.  Happened on my Nexus 4.