# Notification with null:null value

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I just received a notification with **null:null** title, it happened because someone has posted a comment on my answer.

[image]

I know question regarding null notification is already asked earlier [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192552/null-notifications-from-android-app-when-the-notification-is-a-new-meta-question) but this new issue is somewhat different than that issue. I assume here we just get null:null titled notification whenever someone post a comment on your answer.

Comment: When I deleted my answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272716/ipaddress-parse-doesnt-exist-in-net-4), which had a few comments, I immediately got five `null: null`-notifications _at once_, even though for each of the comments I did receive a proper notification earlier.

Answer (score 3):

We will no longer dispatch any messages that have no title or body after the next build.